# Token Encode keeps giving an error when ran

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, discord

I wrote the encoded token in utf-8 in a JSON file when running the script it returns:

```
 File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:artic\Users\A\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Discord.py-Template\main.py", line 23, in run 
    config = config_load()
  File "c:\Users\artic\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Discord.py-Template\main.py", line 14, in config_load
    return json.load(doc)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 335, in loads
    raise JSONDecodeError("Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)",
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

line one of the JSON file is written

```
{"token":"/x4d/x54/x41/x7a/x4f/x44/x6b/x32/x4f/x44/x59/x33/x4d/x44/x59/x79/x4d/x7a/x4d/x33/x4f/x54/x51/x34/x4f/x41/x2e/x47/x76/x4e/x6a/x33/x47/x2e/x53/x66/x41/x52/x64/x46/x78/x4a/x6d/x6a/x67/x6c/x58/x4e/x4e/x61/x65/x56/x35/x78/x57/x6e/x62/x3/6x32/x53/x41/x32/x38/x67/x54/x2d/x51/x4d/x5f/x64/x69/x41"}
```

The decoder

```
with open('data/config.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as doc:
```

Decode the token and activate the bot script, it returned an error message.

Answer (score 0):

`with open('data/config.json', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as doc:`

**Try This**